# How to break inifine loop in a event driven architecture?

Tags: events, architecture, microservices, event-driven, event-driven-design

To understand the issue I provide a simplified diagram of my system:

[image]

1. Let's see the Business service allows you to create an account. It generates `1. Business event`.
2. The event is processed by the Integration service that sends information about it to the External service via `2. API request`.
3. The External service sends a `3. Webhook` with information that a new customer has been created.
4. Then the webhook is processed by the Integration service which converts it to `4. Integration event`.

Unfortunately, the integration event is supposed to add customers created in the External System. The purpose of this is that a new account can be created both in the Business Service as well as in the External Service. The data state should be synchronized in both services.

So I have 2 cases:

- Customer is created in the Business service so the cycle should be stopped after adding a customer to an external system
- Customer is created in the External service and the cycle should be stopped after adding it to the Business service

The customer create flow is just an example as there are many other cases where the same schema applies e.g. customer data update, customer purchase, customer purchase update, and so on.

I look for a generic solution that will allow me to detect somehow that cycle should be broken. I considered a few ideas:

- attach to the event some metadata with the source of an action and based on that break the cycle. The problem is that the information is lost after sending data to the External service.
- Calculate hash from the event payload but the problem I see the event may include e.g. timestamps or other date-like data generated dynamically. For example in the case of a customer creating timestamp from the Business service the External service may be different as the External service creates a timestamp on its own.

Comment: Attaching information about the source system was my find idea as well. Could you please elaborate on this statement of yours: _The problem is that the information is lost after sending data to the External service._?

Comment: The External Service does not allow to pass e.g. custom data field source that later could be returned/checked in the webhook payload. I can only pass data specified by the External Service API specification.

Comment: That's weird. Usually systems are designed to provide the ability to add arbitrary data for round-tripping. Anyway, can you somehow correlate an API request with the related webhook message?

Comment: > Anyway, can you somehow correlate an API request with the related webhook message?
Theoretically yes, when I e.g. add a customer to External Service I can set a `referenceId` that refers to a customer in Business Service. This value is later returned in the webhook. Firstly I wanted to save this value in the Integration service and when the webhook is sent just check if it exists and omit a webhook in this case. But it only covers inserts, the issue for updates/deletes is still the case then.